# Move dynamic text box higher, if it wraps, to stop it from covering up the next text box below or

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, createjs, easeljs

I have two dynamic text boxes placed above each other. Sometimes the first text box wraps into two lines which means it covers up the second text box. How can I detect the first text box has wrapped into two lines and if so, move the text box little higher (I can't move 2nd text box and first text box has some space above it that can be used).

Thanks

Comment: post your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the bounds of the text.

```
var bounds = text1.getBounds();
// Note, add in bounds.y to account for the text baseline
text2.y = text1.y + bounds.y + bounds.height + paddingValue;
```

Bounds is fairly accurate, but not perfect.